# When did Cyclops die (X-men 2021)

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, continuity, cyclops

In X-Men (2021) #6 it is mentioned that Cyclops can not  go out in public due to recently being seen dying in public.
But when I read X-Men #5 he seemed alive and well.

Is this referencing a death that happened a while ago?
Or in another comic running in parallel?
Which comic?

Comment: I'm practically sure they usually mention in which issue it happened when that kind of information is mentioned, somewhere on the page in a yellow square.

Comment: Maybe it's referring to _House of X_? I don't really keep up with X-Men stuff but that seems like a likely possibility?

Comment: It is most likely referred to his death in *The Immortal X-Men*, found this online about it: [Death of Cyclops](https://screenrant.com/immortal-x-men-cyclops-death-teased-marvel-comics/)

Comment: @Frames Catherine White   Do you mean that in  X-Men (2021) #6  Cyclops is alive but can't go out in public because he recently died in public so being seen alive would confuse the public?  Or do you mean someone asked why Cyclops hasn't been seen in public lately and was told that Cyclops died?

Comment: @M.A.Golding I think Cyclops is using a different kind of costume, looks different and isn't replying when people ask him who he is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is addressed via flashback in [X-Men (2021) #7](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/91395/x-men_2021_7).

> Animal-chimera minions of Dr. Stasis attack in New York. One minion grabs a human baby, charges Cyclops and hurls the baby at him. Cyclops catches the baby, putting himself in a vulnerable position. The minion takes advantage and badly wounds Cyclops. After returning the baby to its mother, Cyclops collapses. A masked figure in a medic's overcoat finishes Cyclops off.